# How to label bars with multiple custom values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I have this dataframe

```
rules count    percentage    groups   weight

A      15      24%            1       10
B      5       2%             2       30
C      25      50%            3       50
```

I have the following code:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(18,9.5)})
plots = sns.barplot(x="rules", y="count", data=df, hue=df['groups'], dodge=False)
percentage = df['percentage'].tolist()
weight = df['weight'].tolist()
patches = plots.patches
for i in range(len(patches)):
   x = patches[i].get_x() + patches[i].get_width()/2
   y = patches[i].get_height()+.09
   plots.annotate('{:.1f}%'.format(percentage[i]), (x, y), ha='center',  va='bottom', size=14)
   plots.annotate('{:.0f}'.format(weight[i]), (x, y), ha='center', va='top', color='white', size=15, fontweight="bold")
```

and I get the following error when trying to annotate the barchart with the percentage.

Inside the barchart is another number corresponding to the weight column in the df.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-0ef14f891711> in <module>()
      7    x = patches[i].get_x() + patches[i].get_width()/2
      8    y = patches[i].get_height()+.09
----> 9    plots.annotate('{:.1f}%'.format(percentage[i]), (x, y), ha='center',  va='bottom', size=14)
     10    plots.annotate('{:.0f}'.format(weight[i]), (x, y), ha='center', va='top', color='white', size=15, fontweight="bold")
     11 plots.set_xticklabels(plots.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, fontsize=15)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As of [`matplotlib 3.4.0`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html#new-automatic-labeling-for-bar-charts) it is better to use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), as explained in [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804). However, that answer doesn't explain how to get both annotations.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# test data
data = {'rules': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'count': [15, 5, 25],
        'percentage': ['24%', '2%', '50%'], 'groups': [1, 2, 3], 'weight': [10, 30, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
ax = sns.barplot(x="rules", y="count", data=df, hue='groups', dodge=False)

# since you are using hue, there are multiple containers
for c in ax.containers:
    # set the bar label based on the y-axis
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center', padding=1)
    # add an annotations with custom labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=df.percentage, label_type='edge', padding=1)

# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure 
ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

[image]

---

- Annotation with two custom labels (`'weight'` and `'percentage'`).

```py
ax = sns.barplot(x="rules", y="count", data=df, hue='groups', dodge=False)

# since you are using hue, there are multiple containers
for c in ax.containers:
    # add an annotations with custom labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=df.weight, label_type='center')
    # add an annotations with custom labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=df.percentage, label_type='edge', padding=1)
    
ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

[image]

---

- The issue with the existing code is there are 9 patches, as can be seen with `print(patches)` or `list(patches)`, which can be resolved by selecting only the patches with a height greater than 0.

  - This occurs because `hue` is being used, but there is only one value in `'groups'` for each value in `'rules'`.

```py
plots = sns.barplot(x="rules", y="count", data=df, hue=df['groups'], dodge=False)
percentage = df['percentage'].tolist()
weight = df['weight'].tolist()
patches = plots.patches

# select patches with a height > 0
patches = [p for p in patches if p.get_height() > 0]

for i, p in enumerate(patches):
    
    x = p.get_x() + patches[i].get_width()/2
    y = p.get_height()+.09
    
    plots.annotate(f'{percentage[i]}', (x, y), ha='center',  va='bottom', size=14)
    plots.annotate(f'{weight[i]:.0f}', (x, y), ha='center', va='top', color='white', size=15, fontweight="bold")
```

[image]